# How do I execute conditional logic based upon the type passed to a VB.NET generic method

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I want to create a VB.NET generic factory method that creates instances of classes (as a home-grown inversion of control container).  If I pass the interface IDoSomething as the generic parameter, I want to return an instance of DoSomething (that implements IDoSomething).  I cannot figure out the syntax of the if statement.  I want to write something like:

```
Public Function Build(Of T) as T  
    If T Is IDoSomething then  
        Return New DoSomething()  
    ElseIf T Is IAndSoOn Then  
        Return New AndSoOn()  
    Else  
        Throw New WhatWereYouThinkingException("Bad")  
    End If  
End Sub
```

But this code does not compile.

Answer (score 4):

```
Public Function Build(Of T) As T
  Dim foo As Type = GetType(T)

  If foo Is GetType(IDoSomething) Then
    Return New DoSomething()
  ...
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function Build(Of T) as T  
    If T.gettype Is gettype(IDoSomething) then  
        Return New DoSomething()  
    ElseIf T.gettype Is gettype(IAndSoOn) Then  
        Return New AndSoOn()  
    Else  
        Throw New WhatWereYouThinkingException("Bad")  
    End If  
End Sub
```